# Brackets - вставка кода

Tags: brackets

Настраивал давно брэкетс, щас переустановил винду и все слетело, а как именно настраивал не помню уже и найти не могу нигде.
Так вот, надо настроить его чтобы когда вставляешь текст в сам редактор, он вставлялся уже со всеми табами и пробелами. Из коробки при вставке текста он выравнен как попало. **Плагин beauty не советовать.** Нужно чтобы он просто красиво вставлял код, например, в уже имеющийся код. И выравнивался так же, как выравнен уже имеющийся код (ну если конечно тот нормально выравнен табами)

Comment: Попробуй Paste and Indent .....